# Google MapMaker: iterating over entries in LRU order

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

Is it possible to iterate over a map created by `MapMaker` in LRU order?  `com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap` has the `ascendingKeySet` and `descendingKeySet` methods, but these don't seem to be available in the map returned by `MapMaker` (an instance of `CustomConcurrentHashMap`).  Do the default iterators use LRU ordering?  A cursory look at the code suggests not.

I'm trying to implement the clone method for a class that contains a MapMaker map, so I need a way to create a clone of the map, maintaining LRU ordering of the map entries.

Synchronization issues aside, if I could iterate over the entries in LRU order, then I could just add the entries to a new instance of a MapMaker map with the same limits and I'd have a workable clone.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not possible.  `MapMaker` doesn't retain global LRU ordering anywhere; the segments maintain *internal* LRU ordering, but that's all.

Comment: In the Cache interface we originally included

    ImmutableMap<K, V> activeEntries(int threshold)

to support fetching the hottest entries. The notion of active didn't mean it was in an explicit order, just the top chunk. By using a upper bound, it could return fewer when combining the segmented chunks. This method was dropped as the feature wasn't already present in the CCHM, but could be reintroduced.

The rational behind CLHM's support was to allow Cassandra to restart to a warm cache and minimize the migration pain of existing code bases (e.g. integrate into JCS).

Comment: It seems that LRU ordering of entries isn't maintained across serialization/de-serialization.  I can't test this because the LRU ordering isn't exposed, but looking at the implementation of the SerializationProxy, it just iterates over the map returned by entrySet() to write the map keys and values to disk.  This means that a de-serialized map would start evicting entries in seemingly arbitrary order.  Am I missing something here or did you decide that preserving LRU ordering of de-serialized maps wasn't important?

Comment: I think we decided that preserving LRU ordering of deserialized maps was unimportant.  The only place LRU ordering is implied in the spec is in `expireAfterAccess`, but I think it's totally a reasonable design call to reset the expiration times upon deserialization.